# Where does file_put_contents save the files to?

Tags: php, file, save

I have read the documentation and it doesn't seem to indicate where can I expect the file to be created. I assumed that If I used file_put_contents on a server then a txt file would be created in the same place where the php file running it is. What am I missing here? I'm trying to save the url's in a text file as well.I just need them on my computer really not on the server.

```
while ($blekr<=$blekko_count)
{
    echo '<a href='.$Blekko[$blekr]['url'].'><h4>'.$Blekko[$blekr]['url_title'].'</h4></a>';
    echo '<p>'.$Blekko[$blekr]['snippet'].'<p>';
    echo '<b>'.$Blekko[$blekr]['engine'].'</b>';
    $file = 'Blekko.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, $Blekko[$blekr]['url'], FILE_APPEND);
    echo '<hr>';
    $blekr++;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specify a different directory (using one or more slashes), the file is saved in the [current working directory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) returns the current working directory; [`chdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) changes it.

Comment: worth noting that [`chdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) *changes* current working directory.

Comment: Should my code work? There hasn't been a file saved to my working directory on my server. I know that it does echo the results.

Comment: @the5thace: If your script doesn't have permission to save a file in the directory, the file will not be saved, though a PHP Warning may be generated depending on the `error_reporting`, `display_errors`, and `log_errors` INI settings.